# Jenkins: How to use bitbucket pull request builder plugin with pipeline project?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I could see from the wiki that the bitbucket pull request builder plugin supports jenkins pipeline projects. However, I could not find any example on how to use it. In the snippet generator drop down also, I could not find the option. Can someone share an example of how to use the plugin to build a pull request from a Jenkins pipeline project ?

Answer (score 0):

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers{
        bitbucketpr(projectPath:'<BIT_BUCKET_PATH>',
        cron:'H/15 * * * *',
        credentialsId:'',
        username:'',
        password:'',
        repositoryOwner:'',
        repositoryName:'',
        branchesFilter:'',
        branchesFilterBySCMIncludes:false,
        ciKey:'',
        ciName:'',
        ciSkipPhrases:'',
        checkDestinationCommit:false,
        approveIfSuccess:false,
        cancelOutdatedJobs:true,
        commentTrigger:'')
    }
}
```

After you set up your Jenkins pipeline, run the job for the first time manually (otherwise the trigger may not work!)

https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-pullrequest-builder-plugin

Comment: Where is the documentation on `<BIT_BUCKET_PATH>`? E.g., which types of URL are supported (ssh, https, ...)? Are repositoryOwner and repositoryName appended to <BIT_BUCKET_PATH> to get the full project URL, or is the full URL supposed to be assigned to projectPath? Where are these parameters documented? I'm sure this is a useful plugin, but missing documentation results in a lot of wasted time in trial and error for the people who don't give up on it right away.

Comment: Also, I searched the plugin code on GitHub and found no mention of parameters like "projectPath" and "repositoryOwner". How is the connection made between these parameters and the corresponding functionality?